# Query in Lists Mathematica - Pivot table

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, query

Recently, I finished a simulation, and I got the following data:

```
{{1.1, 11, 0.00107393, 0.0988187},
{1.1, 12, 0.00172679, 0.173259},
{1.1, 13, 0.0022463, 0.236371},
{1.1, 14, 0.00267865, 0.290542},
(...)
{6., 56, 0.582203, 0.83586},
{6., 57, 0.583993, 0.838513},
{6., 58, 0.585727, 0.841082},
{6., 59, 0.587406, 0.843571},
{6., 60, 0.589035, 0.845982}}
```

Where I have $\beta_1(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ and $\beta_2(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, for {$\lambda_1$, 1.1, 6.0, 0.1} $\times$ {$\lambda_2$, 11, 60, 1}. The complete data set is in this [file](https://goo.gl/2e1uBL).

Now, I'd like to plot the series of $\beta_1$ for some set of $\lambda_2$ (i.e. Mod[$\lambda_2$,6] == 0]) as a function of $\lambda_2$ (x-axis). I tried to do some transform using Table[] and 2 iterators, but this was not very piratical, and I'll soon have more data. Also, I really believe Mathematica must have a solution for this, it's trivial.

In time, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are loss rates, so, if anybody would also have nice suggestions for plots, I'd be very glad. This is the one I could make so far, but it's too polluted - I'm a complete beginner at Mathematica:

[image]

$\beta_1 \to$ Full line
$\beta_2 \to$ Dashed line

Please, I'm getting desperate. All I want is to run a simple query to use this table to create a plot, that splits the data in series of $\lambda_2$, so I can have $\beta_1^{\lambda_2}(\lambda_1)$. I really need this ASAP, and I'm starting to considering take this data to another program, that would do this in 3 minutes.

Thank you all for your help!

Regards!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the warming welcome. I read the tutorial, it's practical. However, I have 2 (meta-)questions: how can I tell SE to recognize Mathematica input? And would you have any suggestions to make my question better?

Comment: Ordinarily, when a figure is inserted using the picture icon above the edit window, it just appears.  Yours did not for some reason, so I fixed it.  You can find general discussions of how to format questions and answers in Mathematica meta.  I suggest you clarify how the `β` are defined.

Comment: Did my post help you to understand how you can construct queries on your data ? Please give quick feedback if you need quick help.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, and it works nicely for the queries. However, I could not do exactly what I meant, basically, I'd like to have a plot for $\beta_1^{\lambda_2}(\lambda_1)$. I think the data must look like this:
{{$\lambda_2$, {$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},{$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},{$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},(...)},{$\lambda_2$, {$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},{$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},{$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},(...)},{$\lambda_2$, {$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},{$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},{$\lambda_1$,$\beta_1$},(...)},(...)}

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson See my edit.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1.

This is a quick start and concerns your request : `b1[lam2]` such that `Mod[lam2,6]==0`

```
mydata = Import["/yourPathTo/data.txt", "Table"]

myXY = Cases[mydata, {lam1_, lam2_, b1_, b2_} /; Mod[lam2, 6] == 0 :> {lam2, b1}]

ListPlot[myXY]
```

[image]

#### 2. Edit

Here is a way to plot your beta1[lambda1] grouped by identical lambda2.

Here are all the lambda2 values:

```
allLam2 = mydata[[All, 2]] // Union
```

> `{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60}`

Then

```
Cases[mydata, {lam1_, lam2_, b1_, b2_} /; lam2 == # :> {lam1, b1}] & /@ allLam2 // 
 ListPlot[Thread[Tooltip[#, allLam2]], Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> allLam2] &
```

[image]

Comment: FYI: You've got my vote.  My answer is intended to be complementary.  For example the `lam2` fields are all integers which makes `GroupBy` easy, but in cases with Real data `==` will be necessary.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Complementary approaches are the purpose of this forum ! ;)  I was actually surprised to be the only one to answer for such a general question which may be of interest for many new Mma users  ... I understand there are tons of similar questions ( like "How I import, select and plot my data"). Is there (or should it be) a reference post for this ? (Maybe i should post this to Meta ?)

Comment: I'll be frank: I am sleeping worse than usual recently and it makes it harder to think clearly.  At first glance I did not understand the question so I passed over it.  After seeing your answer I thought "oh, so *that's* what he meant."  I know there are other questions that are related but again the thinking is not so good and I can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

SquareOne's second example is inefficient as the data must be scanned repeatedly, once for each value in `allLam2`.  A more efficient approach is to use [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) or [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html), or occasionally a [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html)/[`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) pairing.

```
mydata = Import["data.txt", "Table"];

selection = GroupBy[mydata, Extract[2] -> Extract[{{1}, {3}}]];

ListLinePlot[Values @ selection, PlotLegends -> Keys @ selection]
```

[image]

Comment: I agree but ... Actually, I thought and tried first with `GatherBy` and `GroupBy`  but I was not happy with it as it seemed less friendly and suitable for the OP profile (new Mma user) than with `Cases` with the explicit pattern matching. It is clear it is a perfect job for `GroupBy` ...  i had some complementary approach in mind ...